# the_content is always surrounded by paragraphs (how to disable or remove them)?

Tags: the-content

`the_content` is always surrounded by paragraphs, it doesn't matter if I'm in HTML view and there's nothing there. Does WordPress have a function to remove them? IS there any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the filter that adds the P is the best option.

```
remove_filter('the_content','wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content','shortcode_autounp'); // You may want to do this aswell
```

Comment: +1 `wpautop` is *really* irritating. It breaks things left and right.

Comment: It's never broken anything for me, i always find it odd that people have such big usses with the editor(i switch modes alot and my code/content is always maintained).

Comment: I've had the autounp break, but if you disable wpautop you can think it's that which is broken. Weird thing is it's an intermittent regex error.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own function in your theme's function.php file and use it instead of "the_content"

```
function my_content($post){
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); // added to parse shortcodes
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt', $content); // added to parse shortcodes
    echo content;
}
```